# How do I change the frequency of the "favorite tags" email?

Tags: support, tag-watching

I have subscribed to emails for my favorite tags on Stack Overflow. The frequency is 15 min. After one day subscription I realized it is flooding my inbox. So I am trying to reduce it to, maybe 3hrs. But the 'edit' link to change the frequency is not working. When I click on the link, it does stay on the same page.

What is the way to change this frequency?

Comment: +1, never knew this feature existed,,,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Go to your account page from any of the Stack Exchange's websites
2. Under the preferences tab(third from left), select `advanced tag subscriptions` (at the bottom of the page)
3. You can add new filters or select pre-set once from the right side column and edit it to suit your needs.

OR

Follow [this link](https://stackexchange.com/filters) and edit your custom Filters.

Answer (score 2):

Go to your user-page, there to your preferences tab, and look at the "inbox emails" point.

Options are 3h, 1d, 7d
I wonder how you got a shorter interval, or whether you might be mistaken...

https://stackoverflow.com/users/preferences/me
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/preferences/me

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I have changed the setting as per your direction. Couple lines below "inbox emails", there is a "Filtered questions" point. For this, I am still seeing the **"Email updates, emailing every 15 min to *****@gmail.com"**. The change you suggested will also take care of changing this frequency?

Comment: Great answer, but this only works for "Unread inbox messages" and not emails for tags, which the OP is asking about. The options for the tag filters are 15 min, 3h, and daily.